# pc starts rebooting when i try to boot from pen drive

Tags: windows-10, bios, usb-flash-drive, reboot, 32-bit

I have windows 10 32-bit and want to change to Windows 10 64-bit. I already transfer the windows 10 64-bit to my pen drive using the steps in windows page. I enter bios and select boot from usb but when I save and exit it won't install windows. Do i need to uninstall the previous version first or something? I am struggling since 2 days ago with this.

My laptop runs with 32 bits but I can't install some game processor allows 64 bits and I have 8 GB of ram.

Comment: add to question: laptop model #, link to specs and manual download, disk partition info.

Comment: What did you do to get Windows 10 on the pen drive? Did you use the Microsoft Creation Tool?

Comment: yes after that i tried with rufus still won't recognize

Comment: You said very old laptop. It is possible it will not run Windows 64-bit

Comment: i checked every step to see if it was everything windows 64 bit needs and it does

Comment: https://pt.dynabook.com/discontinued-products/satellite-a660-17j/ thats the laptop and it used to have a 64 bit windows  but since it went fixing a few months ago i gave it to my sister now i was trying to install a game and it needed a 64 bit windows version thats why i am doing this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install 64-bit over 32-bit. You must remove the 32-bit operating system (normally by formatting) and then install the 64-bit machine fresh.

When done, if you need a 32-bit machine, you can make a 32-bit virtual machine. That should fit fine within 8GB of memory total.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106393/discussion-on-answer-by-john-pc-starts-rebooting-when-i-try-to-boot-from-pen-dri).